# VB.Net with mySql issue?

Tags: mysql, vb.net-2010

I am Searching and Block registration for duplicate ID from mysql Database using VB.Net 2010.
I have got: you have an error in your sql syntax....

Please can you to help me in this?
What will be the mistake i made?
What will be the correct way?

```
Imports System.IO
Imports MySql.Data.MySqlClient
Imports System.Data.SqlClient

    Public Class Add_Clients
        Private Sub CheckClient()
            Dim myquery As String = ""
            Dim mycmd As MySqlCommand

            myquery = "select * from clients where client_id=" & clid.Text
            mycmd = New MySqlCommand(myquery, con)
            Dim idno As Integer = mycmd.ExecuteNonQuery()

            If idno < 0 Then
      MsgBox("The Client is already Exist!", MsgBoxStyle.Exclamation, "Car Rental System")
                Return
            End If

        End Sub
```

Comment: Your SQL Statement is wrong. the whole statement should be inside the Double Codes e.g "select * from clients where client_id=clid.Text"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your query should be like this...

```
 myquery = "SELECT * FROM clients WHERE client_id='" & clid.Text.Replace("'","''").Trim() & "'"
```

The additional `.Replace("'","''").Trim()` should protect you from SQL injection. This should work for now... But you later have you use parametized queries to avoid SQL hacks :) So for now, practice SQL statements first.

Comment: Thanks very much. Nice advise really!

Comment: Your welcome :) Practice SQL statements first... Then move on to parametized queries :) One step at a time.

Answer (score 0):

You should use a parameterized query. It simplifies the code while guarding against injection attacks.

```
myquery = "select * from clients where client_id=@clid" 
**mycmd = New MySqlCommand(myquery, con)**
mycmd.Parameters.AddWithValue("@clid", clid.Text);
```

Comment: Your code has error near mycmd "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." check it!

Comment: You have a point, but i do not see where your con(nection) object is being set either. In any case, you should get into the habit of using parameters.